# Error at installing Microsoft SQL Server 2017 Database engine services and uninstalling multiple instances

Tags: sql-server, installation, sql-server-2017

I am trying to install Microsoft SQL Server 2017 with SQL Server 2017 media installation tool, but next error occurs at installation:

> PerfLib 2.0 counter removal failed with exit code 2. Command line:
>   C:\WINDOWS\system32\unlodctr.exe /m:hkengperfctr.xml from directory
>   C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Shared.

Also I have read many topics of same issue and tried given solutions in those, but like in those topics nothing seems to work.

Now when I have tried installation many times I have many instances like `MSSQLSERVER`, `MSSQLSERVER2` etc, but when I try to uninstall some instances (from control panel->programs->programs and features) there is no Microsoft SQL Server 2017 (64-bit) to continue the uninstalling.

Edit: 
I tried reinstall sql server and this comes at the end: Unbale to install SQL Server (setup.exe).

> Exit code (Decimal): -2147467259Error description: The system cannot
>   find path specified Log reads as below: Overall summary:   Final
>   result:                  Failed: see details below   Exit code
>   (Decimal):           -2147467259   Start time:
>   2019-06-13 11.45.22   End time:                      2019-06-13
>   11:46:14   Requested action:              Install
>
> Setup completed with required actions for features. Troubleshooting
>   information for those features:   Next step for SQLEngine:       Use
>   the following information to resolve the error, uninstall this
>   feature, and then run the setup process again.
>
> Machine Properties:   Machine name:                  DESKTOP-4O7MKHS
>   Machine processor count:       4   OS version:
>   Microsoft Windows 10 Home (10.0.17763)   OS service pack:
>   OS region:                     Suomi   OS language:
>   suomi (Suomi)   OS architecture:               x64   Process
>   architecture:          64 Bit   OS clustered:                  No
>
> Product features discovered:   Product              Instance
>   Instance ID                    Feature
>   Language             Edition              Version         Clustered 
>   Configured   SQL Server 2017      MSSQLSERVER
>   MSSQL14.MSSQLSERVER            Database Engine Services
>   1033                 Developer Edition    14.0.1000.169   No
>   Yes          SQL Server 2017      MSSQLSERVER1
>   MSSQL14.MSSQLSERVER1           Database Engine Services
>   1033                 Developer Edition    14.0.1000.169   No
>   Yes          SQL Server 2017      SQLSERVER
>   MSSQL14.SQLSERVER              Database Engine Services
>   1033                 Developer Edition    14.0.1000.169   No
>   Yes          SQL Server 2017      SQLSERVER1
>   MSSQL14.SQLSERVER1             Database Engine Services
>   1033                 Developer Edition    14.0.1000.169   No
>   Yes          SQL Server 2017      ASDASD               MSSQL14.ASDASD 
>   Database Engine Services                 1033
>   Developer Edition    14.0.1000.169   No         Yes          SQL
>   Server 2017      TESTISERVER          MSSQL14.TESTISERVER
>   Database Engine Services                 1033
>   Developer Edition    14.0.1000.169   No         Yes          SQL
>   Server 2017      TESTISERVER2         MSSQL14.TESTISERVER2
>   Database Engine Services                 1033
>   Developer Edition    14.0.1000.169   No         Yes
>
> Package properties:   Description:                   Microsoft SQL
>   Server 2017    ProductName:                   SQL Server 2017   Type: 
>   RTM   Version:                       14   SPLevel:
>   0   Installation location:
>   C:\SQLServer2017Media\Developer_ENU\x64\setup\   Installation edition:
>   Developer
>
> Product Update Status:   User selected not to include product updates.
>
> User Input Settings:   ACTION:                        Install
>   ADDCURRENTUSERASSQLADMIN:      false   AGTSVCACCOUNT:
>   NT Service\SQLAgent$MSSQLSERVER01   AGTSVCPASSWORD:
>   *****   AGTSVCSTARTUPTYPE:             Manual   ASBACKUPDIR:                   Backup   ASCOLLATION:                   Latin1_General_CI_AS
>   ASCONFIGDIR:                   Config   ASDATADIR:
>   Data   ASLOGDIR:                      Log   ASPROVIDERMSOLAP:
>   1   ASSERVERMODE:                  TABULAR   ASSVCACCOUNT:
>      ASSVCPASSWORD:                    ASSVCSTARTUPTYPE:
>   Automatic   ASSYSADMINACCOUNTS:               ASTELSVCACCT:
>      ASTELSVCPASSWORD:              
>   ASTELSVCSTARTUPTYPE:           0   ASTEMPDIR:                     Temp
>   BROWSERSVCSTARTUPTYPE:         Disabled   CLTCTLRNAME:
>      CLTRESULTDIR:                     CLTSTARTUPTYPE:
>   0   CLTSVCACCOUNT:                    CLTSVCPASSWORD:
>      CLTWORKINGDIR:                 
>   COMMFABRICENCRYPTION:          0   COMMFABRICNETWORKLEVEL:        0
>   COMMFABRICPORT:                0   CONFIGURATIONFILE:
>   C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Setup
>   Bootstrap\Log\20190613_114522\ConfigurationFile.ini   CTLRSTARTUPTYPE:
>   0   CTLRSVCACCOUNT:                   CTLRSVCPASSWORD:
>      CTLRUSERS:                        ENABLERANU:
>   false   ENU:                           true   EXTSVCACCOUNT:
>      EXTSVCPASSWORD:                   FEATURES:
>   SQLENGINE   FILESTREAMLEVEL:               0   FILESTREAMSHARENAME:
>      FTSVCACCOUNT:                     FTSVCPASSWORD:
>      HELP:                          false
>   IACCEPTPYTHONLICENSETERMS:     false   IACCEPTROPENLICENSETERMS:
>   false   IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS:  true   INDICATEPROGRESS:
>   true   INSTALLSHAREDDIR:              C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\   INSTALLSHAREDWOWDIR:           C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\   INSTALLSQLDATADIR:             
>   INSTANCEDIR:                   C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server
>   INSTANCEID:                    MSSQLSERVER01   INSTANCENAME:
>   MSSQLSERVER01   ISMASTERSVCACCOUNT:            NT AUTHORITY\Network
>   Service   ISMASTERSVCPASSWORD:              ISMASTERSVCPORT:
>   8391   ISMASTERSVCSSLCERTCN:          
>   ISMASTERSVCSTARTUPTYPE:        Automatic   ISMASTERSVCTHUMBPRINT:
>      ISSVCACCOUNT:                  NT AUTHORITY\Network Service 
>   ISSVCPASSWORD:                    ISSVCSTARTUPTYPE:
>   Automatic   ISTELSVCACCT:                     ISTELSVCPASSWORD:
>      ISTELSVCSTARTUPTYPE:           0   ISWORKERSVCACCOUNT:
>   NT AUTHORITY\Network Service   ISWORKERSVCCERT:                
>   ISWORKERSVCMASTER:                ISWORKERSVCPASSWORD:
>      ISWORKERSVCSTARTUPTYPE:        Automatic
>   MATRIXCMBRICKCOMMPORT:         0   MATRIXCMSERVERNAME:
>      MATRIXNAME:                       MRCACHEDIRECTORY:
>   NPENABLED:                     0   PBDMSSVCACCOUNT:
>      PBDMSSVCPASSWORD:              
>   PBDMSSVCSTARTUPTYPE:           0   PBENGSVCACCOUNT:
>      PBENGSVCPASSWORD:              
>   PBENGSVCSTARTUPTYPE:           0   PBPORTRANGE:
>      PBSCALEOUT:                    false   PID:
>   *****   QUIET:                         true   QUIETSIMPLE:                   false   ROLE:                             RSINSTALLMODE:
>   DefaultNativeMode   RSSVCACCOUNT:                  
>   RSSVCPASSWORD:                    RSSVCSTARTUPTYPE:
>   Automatic   SAPWD:                            SECURITYMODE:
>      SQLBACKUPDIR:                     SQLCOLLATION:
>   Finnish_Swedish_CI_AS   SQLSVCACCOUNT:                 NT
>   Service\MSSQL$MSSQLSERVER01   SQLSVCINSTANTFILEINIT:         true
>   SQLSVCPASSWORD:                   SQLSVCSTARTUPTYPE:
>   Automatic   SQLSYSADMINACCOUNTS:           DESKTOP-4O7MKHS\Juhani
>   SQLTELSVCACCT:                 NT Service\SQLTELEMETRY$MSSQLSERVER01
>   SQLTELSVCPASSWORD:                SQLTELSVCSTARTUPTYPE:
>   Automatic   SQLTEMPDBDIR:                  
>   SQLTEMPDBFILECOUNT:            4   SQLTEMPDBFILEGROWTH:           64
>   SQLTEMPDBFILESIZE:             8   SQLTEMPDBLOGDIR:
>      SQLTEMPDBLOGFILEGROWTH:        64   SQLTEMPDBLOGFILESIZE:
>   8   SQLUSERDBDIR:                     SQLUSERDBLOGDIR:
>      SUPPRESSPRIVACYSTATEMENTNOTICE: false   TCPENABLED:
>   0   UIMODE:                        Normal   UpdateEnabled:
>   false   UpdateSource:                  MU   USEMICROSOFTUPDATE:
>   false   X86:                           false
>
> Configuration file:            C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\140\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20190613_114522\ConfigurationFile.ini
>
> Detailed results:   Feature:                       Database Engine
>   Services   Status:                        Failed   Reason for failure:
>   An error occurred during the setup process of the feature.   Next
>   Step:                     Use the following information to resolve the
>   error, uninstall this feature, and then run the setup process again.
>   Component name:                SQL Server Database Engine Services
>   Instance Features   Component error code:          0x80004005   Error
>   description:             The system cannot find the path specified
>   Error help link:
>   https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?LinkId=20476&ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&EvtSrc=setup.rll&EvtID=50000&ProdVer=14.0.1000.169&EvtType=0xF57C3D6F%400xDC80C325&EvtType=0xF57C3D6F%400xDC80C325
>
> Feature:                       SQL Browser   Status:
>   Passed
>
> Feature:                       SQL Writer   Status:
>   Passed
>
> Feature:                       SQL Client Connectivity   Status:
>   Passed
>
> Feature:                       SQL Client Connectivity SDK   Status:
>   Passed
>
> Rules with failures:
>
> Global rules:
>
> Scenario specific rules:
>
> Rules report file:               C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\140\Setup
>   Bootstrap\Log\20190613_114522\SystemConfigurationCheck_Report.htm

Comment: Please copy the log from strap folder

Comment: Did I add the right log or if not where it is located?

Comment: Same here, Exit code (Decimal): -2147467259
It happens with both the Express & Evaluation version of SQL Server 2017
Trying the 2019 trial version now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

according to the log file you need to check the following:
1- the specified path you mention as MSSQL server base directory is valid 
2- the specified path you mention as MSSQL server data directory is valid 
3- (if step 1 and 2 did not help)user account is not corrupted, for testing create local user and grant it administrator permission and try installing the server again.

Comment: 1. & 2. The directory should be valid (I'm going with basic installation and default setting with SQL Server 2017 Developer edition installer). 3. I made new account with administrator privileges, tried the installation and I get same error

Comment: Okay I installed 2019 version and it seems to work. I really don't know why 2017 just didn't work but with 2019 I got Microsoft Sql Server 2019 (64-bit) to control panel and now I'm removing extra instances. Thank you for your help!